# Accidentally created the wrong tag

Tags: support, tags

While posting a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54689922/5490505) on [Azure Cosmos DB's Gremlin API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction), I created the [azure-cosmosdb-graphapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-graphapi) tag (to complement the existing [azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi), [azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi), and [azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api) tags)

At the time, I *thought* Azure Cosmos DB called its Gremlin API the "Graph API"--hence the name [azure-cosmosdb-graphapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-graphapi). Shortly after clicking the "create tag button", I decided to double check and found that the proper name is the [Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction) (I should have double checked *before* creating the tag).

So I updated my question with a new [azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi) tag and removed the [azure-cosmosdb-graphapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-graphapi) tag, but the old, [azure-cosmosdb-graphapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-graphapi) tag still seems to exist without any questions (i.e. someone else can now create a question using it).

Am I correct in thinking that the old tag is something a moderator will want to destroy (given that someone might mistakenly use it instead of the correct [azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi) tag?)

Thanks! (and sorry!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be too worried about it! It will get deleted automatically when the process runs this evening if it's not applied to any questions.

No action needed on anyone's part if it's not in use, which it isn't.